# What is exactly this error I'm getting here? (iOS, Xcode, Healthkit)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, healthkit

```
func reuqestConnection(){
    var permReq: Set? = [HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRateVariabilitySDNN),
                        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .restingHeartRate),
                        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)]
    if let healthStore = healthStore{
        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: permReq){ (success, error) in
            if(!success){
                //redirect to error view to try again.
            }
        }
    }
}//func ends
```

That's the code, there's nothing else apart from the init function which just defines the HKHealthStore. The error I get is while requesting Authorization for

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Set<HKQuantityType?>?' to expected argument type 'Set<HKObjectType>?'
```

I'm not sure what this means as I previously did not get this error. What am I supposed to be doing here?

Comment: You are filling the array with items of a type (Set<HKQuantityType?>?) while the expected one is another one (Set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
Currently I used forcefully unwrapping for `HKObjectType.quantityType`. You need to handle this.

```
func reuqestConnection(){
    var permReq: Set = [HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRateVariabilitySDNN)!,
                        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .restingHeartRate)!,
                        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!]
    if let healthStore = healthStore{
        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: permReq ){ (success, error) in
            if(!success){
                //redirect to error view to try again.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, I missed the !. Thanks!